# Is there a formula in excel or VBA logic to sort multiple numbers for from and to?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to sort thousands of document numbers range from and to in excel. It would help me a lot if someone could help me create an excel formula or VBA logic in this problem.

For example I have document numbers 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 15, 17. I want the output to be:

from 1 to 3

from 5 to 7

from 11 to 12

from 15 to 15

from 17 to 17

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: is each number in its own cell?

Comment: Yes, also the numbers is on one column

Comment: What have you tried so far? Help us help you :)

Comment: what is the logic behind your groupings? Why are 15 and 17 their own range? why is 11-12 only 2 items, but 1-3 and 5-7 are 3 items?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I can't think of any :(. The logic for the groupings is to eliminate the numbers that is not in the range. for example I have 10 document numbers that is all different, "1001, 1002, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010, 1019" what I need is the from and to of these numbers so the output will be 1001 - 1002, 1004 - 1010, then 1019 the last number should be 1019 - 1019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably cleaner ways but with this setup:

[image]

Formula in cell `D2`:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F1,$A$1:$A$10,0)+1):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F2,$A$1:$A$10,0)),1),A1)
```

Formula in cell `F2` (***enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>***):

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$11-$A$1:$A$10<>1,ROW($A$1:$A$10),""),ROW()-1))
```

Drag down till column F hits an error...